# if the LI tag has a class of active it will go to the last position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple `li` tag, if the user clicks one of those tags it will have a `class` of active and then the `li` tag will go to the end position of the list. but if the user decided to click the `li` tag it will remove the class and the `li` tag will go back to the previous position.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button.move").on('click', function(){
  $(".active").insertAfter("li:last-child()");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="move">move</button>
    <ul>
    <li class="active">1st list item</li>
    <li>2nd list item</li>
    <li>3rd list item</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please add code to make [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RJC Can you elaborate with example what you have done and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I saw the sample code on the other post. If the user click the move button the active class will go to the end of the list. The result that I want is if the user click one of those li it will have active class then it will go to the end of the list. but if the user click it again it will go to the previous position when the li tag is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your list `flex` (*or `grid` as [david](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64317088/if-the-li-tag-has-a-class-of-active-it-will-go-to-the-last-position/64317262?noredirect=1#comment113732313_64317262) mentions in the comments*) and use the `order` property on the `li` when you want to re-order them.

So no real change is happening in the DOM, but the `.active` element will be shown in the end.

```js
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const element = e.target;
  const isLI = element.nodeName === 'LI';
  if (isLI) {
    element.classList.toggle('active');
    removeClassFromSiblings(element, 'active');
  }
})

function removeClassFromSiblings(element, classname) {
  let prev = element;
  let next = element;
  // remove active from preceeding elements
  while (prev = prev.previousElementSibling) {
    prev.classList.remove('active');
  }
  // remove active from following elements
  while (next = next.nextElementSibling) {
    next.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex; /* or grid */
  flex-direction: column; /* if using flex */
}

.active {
  order: 1;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
  <li>fifth</li>
  <ul>
```

Comment: It's worth noting - but not worth another answer - that this approach works with CSS Grid as well: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/euby86vL/), if you - Gabriele - would like to add it to your answer to be more complete? :)